# get number of failed user login results from oracle db using spring mvc mybatis

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am kind of stuck on this. because Tomcat doesn't show any error but my data is not retrieving from the database.
I want to select from the database number of user failed to login history data.

here is my service code

```
    public int getUserResetFail(LoginHistoryVO id)  {

    ArrayList<LoginHistoryVO>  list = loginHistoryDao.selectLoginHistory(id);
    int failCount = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {

        if(list.get(i).getState().equals(LoginHistoryVO.FAIL)) {
            failCount++;
        } else if(list.get(i).getState().equals(LoginHistoryVO.SUCCESS)) {
            failCount = 0;
        }
        else  {
            failCount = 0;
        }

    }

    return failCount;

}
```

controller where I want to check the number of failed results

```
LoginHistoryVO userID = new LoginHistoryVO();
            userID.getId();

            int numOfFails =  loginHistorySvc.getUserResetFail(userID);
```

and Dao code

```
public interface LoginHistoryDao {


public void insertLoginHistory(LoginHistoryVO vo);

ArrayList<LoginHistoryVO> selectLoginHistory(LoginHistoryVO id);
```

}

batis code where I want to get data

```
<select id="selectLoginHistory" resultMap="loginHistory">

    SELECT USER_ID, STATE, LOGTIME FROM
    (
    SELECT USER_ID = #{id}
    FROM LOGIN_HISTORY
    ORDER BY LOGTIME DESC
    )resultSet
    WHERE ROWNUM = 5;

</select>
```

my Oracle database `CREATE TABLE LOGIN_HISTORY 
(
  USER_ID VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, LOGTIME TIMESTAMP(6) 
, STATE VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) 
)`

tomcat error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at tom.monitoring.restapi.AccountApiCtr.auth(AccountApiCtr.java:152)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hint: `rownum <=5` -- means use `<=`

Comment: I tried it no result. in tomcat cmd I am getting this error `ava.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at tom.monitoring.restapi.AccountApiCtr.auth(AccountApiCtr.java:152)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)`

Comment: This is not related error.

Comment: i mean adding makes no sense still this error appears

Comment: Ok.. but rownum must not be used with equals operator unless it is compared against 1